# How to transform Flow<T> to Flow<List<T>> in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have a completable flow of items like Flow. I would like to transform this flow to Flow<List> with a list of all items.

I've tried to use

```
public fun <T> Flow<T>.toList(): Flow<List<T>> = flow {
    val list = toList(mutableListOf())
    emit(list.toImmutableList())
}
```

but this function never emit value

Comment: Do you mean you want to return a flow of a single element that is the list of all elements in the initial flow?

Comment: @Joffrey yes, it is

Comment: What is `toImmutableList()` here? This is the only thing I needed to remove because I don't have the library to properly reproduce. Otherwise I believe the only issue is that the name `toList()` already exists (and actually you're using it). Try naming your function a different way.

Comment: @Joffrey  I use `toImmutableList` to return immutable list definitely.
BTW renaming doesn't work

Comment: Okays, looks like simple test works. Maybe the issue with flatMapConcat that I used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I have to say there is no real point in creating a `Flow` of one element. Of course it's not a problem if the flow sometimes has one element and sometimes more. But if the flow you create always contains a single element, it's likely you should just use a suspend function returning that element instead.

Interestingly enough.. you already have that suspend function in the coroutines library and it's `toList()`:

```kotlin
// no need to create a flow out of it
val list = myFlow.toList().toImmutableList()
```

If you *really* want a flow that contains a single `List<T>` element, then I think you got it right.
The single element will be the list of all items in the initial flow.

I think your issue might be that the `Flow.toList()` function already exists.
Try naming it differently:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
  val initialFlow = List(5) { it }.asFlow()
  
  initialFlow.toSingleListItem().collect {
      println(it)
  }
}

public fun <T> Flow<T>.toSingleListItem(): Flow<List<T>> = flowOf(toList().toImmutableList())
```

You can run it here:
https://pl.kotl.in/frCg831WM

Comment: "no real point in creating a Flow of one element" --  Using Flow<> as return values from Room Dao seems like it would be valuable to observe changes in a <Int> just as well as observing changes to a List<Int>, no?

Comment: By definition, a flow of one element doesn't allow to observe changes, since you have only one value (you don't get updates). This is why I say there is usually no point in doing this

Comment: "flow of one element cannot be observed" : do you have any references for this? I haven't been able to locate anything. I tried using "fun getActiveWorkout(): Flow<String?>" in my Dao, and this does indeed appear to trigger UI to update when the content of the Databasle string changes.

Comment: Check this: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-flow-273acffe5b57 

@Query("SELECT * FROM Dog WHERE name = :name")
fun getDog(name: String): Flow<Dog>

Now, if we call getDog("Frida"), Flow will return one object: (Frida, 11, 3)

Whenever any changes are made to the table, independent of which row is changed, the query will be re-triggered and the Flow will emit again. So if Frida gets updated, we will receive the latest info.

Comment: *Flow will return one object whenever X* - so it's not a flow of one element. My point was that if you use `flowOf(42)` you will collect 42 once from it, and then it's over. So you won't get updates, because it's a single element. I am *not* talking about flows of non-collection element types of course, just flows of literally *one* element, and more specifically flows that are statically provable to always be of one element, such as those built with `flowOf`. Unless you implement an abstraction requiring flow, you're usually better off with a suspend function when you return one element

Comment: @Mike I'm sorry it took me so long to realize where the confusion was, btw. So just to clarify again, I was not making a point about `Flow<Int>` vs `Flow<List<Int>>`. I was making a point about flows that yield a *single* `Int`, or a *single* `List<Int>`, and then complete. In the OP's code, `flow { emit(list) }` is a flow of a single element, which is a list. And this is usually pointless and instead could be a simple suspend function returning that list directly